# Xcode 9 - Some folders marked with red text

Tags: ios, directory, xcode9

In my project, there are some folders that have red text.
The project compiles and everything works, but I can't understand why only some folders have red text.

[image: Folder with red text]

Comment: It means they are not found on disk where your project believes they should be.  Control-click and Show In Finder to see the folder location to locate the file and drag it back in to the project, and delete the bad reference.Missing. Maybe you moved them somewhere without deleting them from the project or something.

Comment: It works, thanks. I think you should post it as an answer

Comment: Happy to help you. also post as a answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Check this.**

It means they are not found on disk where your project believes they should be. Control-click and Show In Finder to see the folder location to locate the file and drag it back in to the project, and delete the bad reference.Missing. Maybe you moved them somewhere without deleting them from the project or something.

Edit: Don't delete it before add it first, and you should save backup from the files in another folder, also you have to use source controls like Bitbucket, GitHub, or GitLab.

Answer (score 1):

The UI error feedback notifies you that the path is not found. You can select a new one using the folder icon in the right panel. In this way, all files in the folder keep the configuration so it is more convenient.

I illustrate it in the above screenshot.

[image: Example]

Comment: is there a way to handle this issue via xcode commandline?

Comment: No that I don't know, an improvement it'd generate the project using a tool as bazel so this problem won't happen again.